# java for kannel delivery report

Tags: java, sms, report, kannel

I have successfully written a class for sending SMS over kannel in Java. But I have big problems to write a delivery report class. Any idea how to write it?

Comment: Can you be more specific with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kannel will send you back the delivery reports in the url you specify in the `dlr-url` parameter in the SMS submission, for example `example.com/DLR?outgoing_id=123&status=%d`.

What language you write it in is irrelevant. All you need is an HTTP page that accepts specific parameters via HTTP GET. Kannel will add parameters for the delivery status, time, et al, and you will link them to your SMS submission via its id as above.

[This discussion](http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-dlr-mask---dlr-url-p3884418.html) has a clear example.